# Why do parentheses around a sequence not surround the entire sequence?

Tags: latex3, l3seq

Sequences in `LaTeX3` are proving very difficult to understand. I'm writing small demos to try to learn the various commands. In this demo, I can input a sequence and then print it. However, when I put parentheses around the sequence, only the first letter of the first element gets surrounded. If I use `\seq_set_from_clist:NN` the output is even stranger, with nothing at all showing in parentheses. What am I obviously not understanding?

Here is my MWE and compiled output.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_demo_myseq_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo_inputseq:n #1 
  {%
    %  get a sequence
    \seq_set_eq:NN \l_demo_myseq_seq #1
    %\seq_set_from_clist:NN \demo_myseq_seq #1
    Forward~sequence~is~(\l_demo_myseq_seq)
  }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\getasequence}{ m }
  {%
    \demo_inputseq:n #1
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\getasequence{red, orange, cyan}
\end{document}
```

[image: Parentheses surround one letter]

[image: Parentheses surround nothing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In expl3, the arguments which are indicated with a lower case letter (n, o, f, x, c, etc.) always need braces. So your `\getasequence` should not use `\demo_inputseq:n #1` but `\demo_inputseq:n { #1 }`. (This caused the actual issue you encountered: Because of the missing braces, only the first token got passed.

Also, `\seq_set_eq:NN` should only be used if you already have a sequence stored in a sequence variable. But you only have a comma separated list which is passed as an argument and not stored in a variable, so you need `\seq_from_clist:Nn` (The lowercase `n` indicates that you do not want to pass a variable.) Additionally, you need to specify in which form the list should be output. In your case, `\seq_use:Nn` might be appropriate: It prints the entries with a given delimiter:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_demo_myseq_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo_inputseq:n #1 
  {%
    %  get a sequence
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_demo_myseq_seq {#1}
    Forward~sequence~is~(\seq_use:Nn \l_demo_myseq_seq {,})
  }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\getasequence}{ m }
  {%
    \demo_inputseq:n {#1}
  }%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\getasequence{red, orange, cyan}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very clearly explained. I did not think to use `seq_use:Nn` I noticed that if I put braces around `#1` in the line that defines `\demo_inputseq:n` I get an `Illegal parameter number in definition of \demo_inputseq:n` message. Why are braces not appropriate there given the presence of `:n`?

Comment: That's a very good question and the answer is a bit complicated, but mostly it ends up being that defining the parameter and actually passing the parameter are quite different operations. The problem is that it would not be clear what this would mean. `\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo:n {#1}` could either be a macro which does not have any parameters and the replacement text is `#1` or it could be a macro with one braced argument and the replacement text follows. So to avoid any confusion, the braces are not allowed.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL To avoid such confusing syntax, you can replace `\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo_inputseq:n #1` with `\cs_new_protected:Nn \demo_inputseq:n`. The `\cs_new...:Nn` functions (without the p) do not need any explicit argument specifiers and instead derive them automatically from the name of the new function. (So it knows that one parameter appears because `:n` is used.)

Comment: Ah yes! I would indeed prefer to consistently use the function signature when defining functions (unless that has a disadvantage).

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL The disadvantages are: It is a bit slower when defining (LaTeX has to translate the signature into the argument specifier) and it doesn't allow you to use more "creative" tricks with arguments (you probably shouldn't do that anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Some more details.

TeX is always the same with respect to macro definitions and argument scanning.

For instance, a sequence is a macro with a specially made replacement text. If we store `a`, `b` and `c` in the sequence `\l_tmpa_seq` and we do

```
\show \l_tmpa_seq
```

we see

```
> \l_tmpa_seq=macro:->\s__seq \__seq_item:n {a}\__seq_item:n {b}\__seq_item:n {c}.
```

The control sequence `\s__seq` is just an alias for `\relax` and the macro `\__seq_item:n` would issue an error message (this is relevant when a sequence is used in an improper context).

The two control sequences are employed as markers for the functions that *use* sequences, such as `\seq_map_inline:Nn` or `\seq_use:Nn` and should ***never*** be used except by the team for defining the programmer level functions.

The function you define with

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \demo_inputseq:n #1
```

takes an argument, but when you call it, the argument should be braced (unless it consists of just one token. Since you call it as

```
\demo_inputseq:n #1
```

and the document has

```
\getasequence{red, orange, cyan}
```

what happens is that TeX will see

```
\demo_inputseq:n red, orange, cyan
```

and the argument will be `r`. This partly explains the output

> (r)ed, orange, cyan

but not all. What happens now is that this input is transformed into

```
\seq_set_eq:NN \l_demo_myseq_seq r Forward~sequence~is~(\l_demo_myseq_seq)ed, orange, cyan
```

The `\seq_set_eq:NN` function is (currently) implemented as `\let` and this is why your erroneous input doesn't issue actual error messages.

A function with signature `:NN` expects two unbraced single token arguments, but it's not possible to *enforce* this: if one does

```
 \seq_set_eq:NN \foo { abc }
```

depending on the actual implementation this might yield an error or not. However, the documentation says that `\seq_set_eq:NN` should be followed by two sequence variable names and the first sequence will be made (locally) identical to the second one. Hence the first variable should start with `\l_` (or `\l__`), while the second variable can be local, global or constant.

As Marcel writes, you can use

```
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_demo_myseq_seq { #1 }
```

but also

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_demo_myseq_seq { , } { #1 }
```

The difference is that the former would ignore “empty” items, whereas the latter wouldn't. For instance

```
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { a, , c }
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
```

yields

```
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {c}.
```

whereas

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { a, , c}
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
```

would yield

```
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {}
>  {c}.
```

Spaces before and after items are ignored. Which strategy to choose depends on the actual need.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information.